# vs code live server extension not working

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, liveserver

I'm trying to run a basic html file with live server extension, when I run it I get  the Server is Started notification(as shown in the img below) but then nothing happens [image]
even manually going to port 5500 like "http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html" I get the following error

Cannot GET /index.html

i tried restarting vs code. uninstalling and reinstalling live server extension also tried uninstalling and reinstalling vs code. i set the default browser in the extension settings and on my computer any other ideas i can try would be appreciated

Thank you

Comment: Not sure if this is the case, it might have something to do with your HTML file. Could I see the directory?

Comment: maybe use `localhost:5500/` maybe is that the problem (sorry if 127.0.0.1 don't work also localhost will not work but maybe try)

Comment: @LaaouatniAnas same thing doesn't work.

Comment: @truongmleon it doesnt work for any file regardless which file i run the results are the same as posted in my question

Comment: @GershyMenzer I saw now that you solved it, good job! yes instead of spaces use `_` or `-`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why but changing file names (removed special characters) worked only if i do it manually it still doesn't load the browser automatically though..

Answer (score 1):

This could be the issue I just solved.

VS code was not using the local IP as a host.

Manage > settings > search "use local" or "live server"> **check** "use local IP as host".

I hope that helps you or your connection needs could be unique and you might want to look at this guide. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/network

Answer (score -1):

It is because you have added insufficient paths in your Environmental variables.

```
First you can do is close the vs code

Go to the properties of My Pc

Click on Advanced Settings

click on Environmental Variables

from there you can add path clicking the path variables in the table shown there 6 . Add a new line to the path and copy paste the path of your system 32
```

C:\Windows\System32

~This is an answer I found on another Question but it worked with me when nothing else worked,hope this solution works in your case :3